# Search mysql using multiple variable from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php with mysql

Hello I have a couple of tables with information about books.

One table is like this

id, bookTitle, BookText

The other is like this

id, bookid, amountofsales

I would like to search the text of the book, and the book title from one table, but also be able to include amountofsales from the other table to give the results a possible bias.

So for instance if book 1 had 50,000 sales, and matched the search "oil" but book 2 had 23,000 sales but also matched "oil" book 1 would be slightly more relevant.

However this should only give a small bias because if one matches oil more then that should still be the top result.

Any ideas?

Comment: What should happen if a book "T **oil** et Jokes" sells 5 milllion copies and "Encyclopedia of **Oil** " sells 10000? Do you want the first to win even though it isn't about oil?

Comment: ^ like Mark says. A possible solution would be to order by `REGEXP '[[:<:]]oil[[:>:]]' DESC` initially (although you could/should keep the `WHERE` clause as simple as possible to get partial result also in there). Or the usual and more appropriate `FULLTEXT` index match score of course.

Comment: Yes that is what I worried about. Also length of the book might become a future indicator. So I would like to be able to give these like a percentage value of something. So bring up results for oil then order by best result taking into consideration a 5% bias on sales maybe and anther 5% bias on book size.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do some joining of your tables:

```
$searchQuery = "oil";

$sql = "SELECT a.bookTitle, a.BookText, b.amountofsales FROM table1 a, table2 b WHERE a.id = b.bookid AND (a.bookTitle LIKE '%".$searchQuery."%' OR a.BookText LIKE '%".$searchQuery."%') SORT BY b.amountofsales DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while( $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result) )
{
  echo $obj->bookTitle." has been sold ".obj->amountofsales." times and is relevant to your search";
}
```

Please have in mind that I haven't tested the code above, but it might give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can relate two tuples from two tables by outlining the MySQL query as follows:

SELECT B.bookTitle, B.bookText, S.amountOfSales FROM book B, sales S WHERE S.id = B.id ORDER BY S.amountOfSale DESC;

This will verify that the id's match (meaning that the different table is relevant, as the id's are the same), and pull all the relevant data. Then you just have to interpret the data.

Be careful with wild-card searches though, they can pull up a lot of unrelated data, say for instance a book about foil may pull up before oil.